# Need a fix for c++ script (not mine)

Tags: c++

I have the following code in a script that I am trying to build.

```
typedef std::vector< typename Sphere::vec_type > VV; 
typedef typename Sphere::vec_type vec_type; 
VV v( count , s.dimension() ); 
for ( int ii=0; ii<count; ++ii ) { 
v[ii] = randomPointOnSurface( s );
```

It produces this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >::_M_fill_initialize(size_t, int&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:1033: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_initialize(size_t, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >]
```

A workaround is to remove s.dimension() but is there any other way that this can fixed?

Comment: What is the data type of `s`? What data type does `s.dimension()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested vector, so you need something like

```
VV v( count , vec_type(s.dimension()) );
```

This initializes each of the `count` inner vectors to have size `s.dimension()`.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed. It compiles using the code you gave me. I'll select the best answer in 5 minutes(I can't do it any faster :( )